# how to add new nfts to a candy machine collection?

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine-v3

I have an nft collection that I have created using candy machine. Now I want to add new nfts to it. How do I add the new nfts to the collection?

Comment: Hi any news on this topic ? I have got the same issue.

Comment: i wonder too we need to keep this thread updated

Answer (score 1):

You can't create new nft's in the created candy machine, but  you can either make a new candymachine and mint them out to the same Collection.